# The MP3 file does not play in the page I mean autoplay failure

Tags: playback, autoplay

I wrote this kod

In HTML part:

```
Audio src="/true.mp3"></audio
```

In script tag:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", event => {

const audio = document.querySelector("audio");

audio.volume = 5;

audio.play();
});
```

I have an MP3 file. When I open the page, all codes run but this part is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be autoplayed without javascript.
Use `<audio src="/true.mp3" autoplay></audio>` to autoplay audio.

**Other controls:**
And you can also use `controls` to show controls, and `loop` to loop the audio.
But user need to interact with the site.